# How do I show a Floating Action Button above a StreamBuilder/ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, flutter-listview

I currently have a page with a scaffold that has a Stream Builder in it's body connected to Cloud Firestore for the database. The StreamView just returns a ListView of the contents of the database.

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').snapshots(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(
                    context,
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index],
                  ));
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          openDialog();
        },
        backgroundColor: Color(Colors.blueAccent.value),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

To add new entries to the database I created a ShowDialog nested in a function called openDialog().

To open that dialog I used a floating action button but it is not appearing on the screen

Edit: Possibly concerning output from flutter run -v:

```
Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '[path to my app]\build\app\intermediates\assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets'. Reason: Task ':app:compressDebugAssets'
uses this output of task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are        
executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

I went to the website but it was java so I don't really understand it.

Comment: This is not supposed to happen. Please upgrade to latest flutter SDK version by running `flutter upgrade` in project dir terminal and restart your pc. If it still doesn't work, uninstall the app from your emulator and reinstall.

Comment: @Delwinn I just tried that but nothing changed. I ran flutter upgrade but it said I was already on latest and uninstalled then reinstalled from VSCode to no change.

Comment: does anything pop up in the terminal. for extended logs, run app using `flutter run -v`

Comment: Since I can't paste (too long) it here I'll edit the post.

Comment: just send the part that you suspect contains the issue.